# Kernel Panic on Guest-VM (Debian 9)

Tags: kvm-virtualization, linux-kernel, qemu, kernel-panic, debian-stretch

I have two servers running with Debian Jessie Kernel 3.16.0-5-amd64. 
Both servers have the exact same configuration, only hardware differs.
I use KVM as hypervisor together with QEMU on both servers.
When i try to install Debian 9 (Kernel 4.*.*) on a Guest virtual machine,
using the official netinstall iso, the guest-vm immediatly goes into kernel panic.

[Debian 9 kernelpanic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n2jOq.png)

Hardware-Specs of the affected server:

```
Server2
    description: Computer
    width: 64 bits
    capabilities: smbios-3.0 vsyscall32
  *-core
       description: Motherboard
       physical id: 0
     *-memory
          description: System memory
          physical id: 0
          size: 62GiB
     *-cpu
          product: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6700 CPU @ 3.40GHz
          vendor: Intel Corp.
          physical id: 1
          bus info: cpu@0
          size: 800MHz
          capacity: 3401MHz
          width: 64 bits
          capabilities: fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp x86-64 constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm 3dnowprefetch ida arat epb xsaveopt pln pts dtherm tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 hle avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid rtm mpx rdseed adx smap clflushopt cpufreq
     *-pci
          description: Host bridge
          product: Intel Corporation
          vendor: Intel Corporation
          physical id: 100
          bus info: pci@0000:00:00.0
          version: 07
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
        *-display UNCLAIMED
             description: VGA compatible controller
             product: Intel Corporation
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
             version: 06
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list
             configuration: latency=0
             resources: memory:f6000000-f6ffffff memory:e0000000-efffffff ioport:f000(size=64)
        *-usb
             description: USB controller
             product: Intel Corporation
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 14
             bus info: pci@0000:00:14.0
             version: 31
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi xhci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=xhci_hcd latency=0
             resources: irq:138 memory:f7020000-f702ffff
           *-usbhost:0
                product: xHCI Host Controller
                vendor: Linux 3.16.0-4-amd64 xhci_hcd
                physical id: 0
                bus info: usb@2
                logical name: usb2
                version: 3.16
                capabilities: usb-3.00
                configuration: driver=hub slots=6 speed=5000Mbit/s
           *-usbhost:1
                product: xHCI Host Controller
                vendor: Linux 3.16.0-4-amd64 xhci_hcd
                physical id: 1
                bus info: usb@1
                logical name: usb1
                version: 3.16
                capabilities: usb-2.00
                configuration: driver=hub slots=12 speed=480Mbit/s
        *-generic UNCLAIMED
             description: Signal processing controller
             product: Intel Corporation
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 14.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:14.2
             version: 31
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
             configuration: latency=0
             resources: memory:f703a000-f703afff
        *-communication UNCLAIMED
             description: Communication controller
             product: Intel Corporation
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 16
             bus info: pci@0000:00:16.0
             version: 31
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi cap_list
             configuration: latency=0
             resources: memory:f7039000-f7039fff
        *-storage
             description: SATA controller
             product: Intel Corporation
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 17
             bus info: pci@0000:00:17.0
             version: 31
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: storage msi pm ahci_1.0 bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=ahci latency=0
             resources: irq:140 memory:f7034000-f7035fff memory:f7038000-f70380ff ioport:f090(size=8) ioport:f080(size=4) ioport:f060(size=32) memory:f7037000-f70377ff
        *-isa
             description: ISA bridge
             product: Intel Corporation
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.0
             version: 31
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: isa bus_master
             configuration: latency=0
        *-memory UNCLAIMED
             description: Memory controller
             product: Intel Corporation
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.2
             version: 31
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz (30.3ns)
             capabilities: bus_master
             configuration: latency=0
             resources: memory:f7030000-f7033fff
        *-serial UNCLAIMED
             description: SMBus
             product: Intel Corporation
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.4
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.4
             version: 31
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             configuration: latency=0
             resources: memory:f7036000-f70360ff ioport:f040(size=32)
        *-network
             description: Ethernet interface
             product: Ethernet Connection (2) I219-LM
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.6
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.6
             logical name: eth0
             version: 31
             serial: 90:1b:0e:a4:a0:25
             size: 1Gbit/s
             capacity: 1Gbit/s
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
             configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=2.3.2-k duplex=full firmware=0.8-4 ip=88.99.64.104 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
             resources: irq:139 memory:f7000000-f701ffff
     *-scsi:0
          physical id: 2
          logical name: scsi1
          capabilities: emulated
        *-disk
             description: ATA Disk
             product: HGST HUS724020AL
             physical id: 0.0.0
             bus info: scsi@1:0.0.0
             logical name: /dev/sda
             version: AA70
             serial: PN1134P5HLSKYW
             size: 1863GiB (2TB)
             capabilities: partitioned partitioned:dos
             configuration: ansiversion=5 logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=512 signature=32202275
           *-volume:0
                description: Linux raid autodetect partition
                physical id: 1
                bus info: scsi@1:0.0.0,1
                logical name: /dev/sda1
                capacity: 32GiB
                capabilities: primary multi
           *-volume:1
                description: Linux raid autodetect partition
                physical id: 2
                bus info: scsi@1:0.0.0,2
                logical name: /dev/sda2
                capacity: 512MiB
                capabilities: primary multi
           *-volume:2
                description: Linux raid autodetect partition
                physical id: 3
                bus info: scsi@1:0.0.0,3
                logical name: /dev/sda3
                capacity: 1830GiB
                capabilities: primary multi
     *-scsi:1
          physical id: 3
          logical name: scsi2
          capabilities: emulated
        *-disk
             description: ATA Disk
             product: HGST HUS724020AL
             physical id: 0.0.0
             bus info: scsi@2:0.0.0
             logical name: /dev/sdb
             version: AA70
             serial: PN1134P5HLKZMW
             size: 1863GiB (2TB)
             capabilities: partitioned partitioned:dos
             configuration: ansiversion=5 logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=512 signature=ed94df1f
           *-volume:0
                description: Linux raid autodetect partition
                physical id: 1
                bus info: scsi@2:0.0.0,1
                logical name: /dev/sdb1
                capacity: 32GiB
                capabilities: primary multi
           *-volume:1
                description: Linux raid autodetect partition
                physical id: 2
                bus info: scsi@2:0.0.0,2
                logical name: /dev/sdb2
                capacity: 512MiB
                capabilities: primary multi
           *-volume:2
                description: Linux raid autodetect partition
                physical id: 3
                bus info: scsi@2:0.0.0,3
                logical name: /dev/sdb3
                capacity: 1830GiB
                capabilities: primary multi
```

I also add the configuration for the guest-vm below

```
<domain type='kvm'>
  <name>Debian9-Test</name>
  <uuid>088a7673-c27a-3d13-c4b8-214c5ea3cf90</uuid>
  <description>None</description>
  <memory unit='KiB'>1048576</memory>
  <currentMemory unit='KiB'>1048576</currentMemory>
  <vcpu placement='static'>8</vcpu>
  <os>
    <type arch='x86_64' machine='pc-1.3'>hvm</type>
    <boot dev='hd'/>
    <boot dev='cdrom'/>
    <bootmenu enable='yes'/>
  </os>
  <features>
    <acpi/>
    <apic/>
    <pae/>
  </features>
  <cpu mode='host-model'>
    <model fallback='allow'/>
  </cpu>
  <clock offset='utc'/>
  <on_poweroff>destroy</on_poweroff>
  <on_reboot>restart</on_reboot>
  <on_crash>restart</on_crash>
  <devices>
    <emulator>/usr/bin/kvm</emulator>
    <disk type='file' device='disk'>
      <driver name='qemu' type='qcow2'/>
      <source file='/var/lib/libvirt/images/Debian9-Test.img'/>
      <target dev='vda' bus='virtio'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x04' function='0x0'/>
    </disk>
    <disk type='file' device='cdrom'>
      <driver name='qemu' type='raw'/>
      <target dev='hda' bus='ide'/>
      <readonly/>
      <address type='drive' controller='0' bus='1' target='0' unit='1'/>
    </disk>
    <controller type='usb' index='0'>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x01' function='0x2'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='pci' index='0' model='pci-root'/>
    <controller type='ide' index='0'>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x01' function='0x1'/>
    </controller>
    <interface type='network'>
      <mac address='52:54:00:32:f5:68'/>
      <source network='br143'/>
      <model type='virtio'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x03' function='0x0'/>
    </interface>
    <serial type='pty'>
      <target port='0'/>
    </serial>
    <console type='pty'>
      <target type='serial' port='0'/>
    </console>
    <input type='tablet' bus='usb'/>
    <input type='mouse' bus='ps2'/>
    <input type='keyboard' bus='ps2'/>
    <graphics type='vnc' port='-1' autoport='yes' listen='0.0.0.0' passwd='Oz92tPz4UfzU'>
      <listen type='address' address='0.0.0.0'/>
    </graphics>
    <video>
      <model type='cirrus' vram='9216' heads='1'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x02' function='0x0'/>
    </video>
    <memballoon model='virtio'>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x05' function='0x0'/>
    </memballoon>
  </devices>
</domain>
```

I already tried to use "pc-i440fx-2.1" but to no effect.

Any ideas are very much appreciated!

**Update:** 
My hoster switched all the hardware, unfortunately the exact same problem still persists. Installation in expert mode results in a different output:

[image]

**Update2:**
After performing a kernelupgrade on the host,
everything seems to work fine now.

Comment: Check that your installation media is not corrupt.

Comment: thanks for this answer, but i already tried serveral netinstall.iso's almost everything from debian-9.0.0-amd64-netinst.iso to debian-9.4.0-amd64-netinst.iso. And installation on Host-Server1 works fine with these images.
This is my iso md5 Hash: 
73bd8aaaeb843745ec939f6ae3906e48  debian-9.4.0-amd64-netinst.iso 
https://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/current/amd64/iso-cd/MD5SUMS
it's not corrupt

Comment: Hmm. My next guess would be bad hardware, then.

Comment: Bad like, bad firmware? Should i contact my hoster about this?

Comment: Bad CPU, bad motherboard, bad RAM, who knows? They're all suspect until you rule them out.

Comment: My hoster will switch the hardware completely except for the harddrives, i will update this question as soon as i know more about this issue.